# Can't make a connection to database in UWP project using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, data-access

I have problem with connecting a database to my UWP.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    string connstring;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        connstring = @" Data Source = tcp:stdgydlcdk.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=doc4cloud_db;User ID=****;Password = ****; version = 3";
    }


    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(connstring)) 
        try
        {
                con.Open();
                if(con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    NewBlogUrl.Text = "succes";
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

                NewBlogUrl.Text = ex.Message +ex.InnerException;
        }

    }
}
```

(instead of stars in connection string, I have valid ID and password)
As you can see in my simple test program here, I am trying to make a connection to a database and print stuff depending on result. The poject runs how it is supposed to but the problem comes when the click action is called. First exception is a ArgumentException, which say that keywords **Initial Catalog=** , **User ID=** , **Password =** and **version =** ,from my connection string ,are not supported,and if I remove one of them, the Exception is thrown for the next one, the second problem is, if I remove all of them(even if I should not), I get rid of ArgumentException but, I get a connection exception now, **The given path's format is not supported** to be more specific. I have all necesary dlls

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source = tcp:stdgydlcdk.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=doc4cloud_db;User ID=****;Password = ****; version = 3");

    }
```

Here I made a model to get acces to my database. Maybe I did something wrong in my model, maybe connection string declaration is wrong, I am not sure. Any feedback is welcome. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [SQLite is Serverless](https://sqlite.org/serverless.html) - SQLite and the Data Source tag tcp:url doesn't sound valid to me. You are sure not mixing SQLite and SQLServer?

Comment: Well my data base is compatible with SQL server witch I gues might make it a SQL server, but does it metters for SQLite?

Comment: Is it required for data base to be a file data base and make direct connection with it? And as far as I know only SQLite can be used as data acces in UWP projects, or my knowledges aren't far enough?

Comment: See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-data-from-935e360c and http://stackoverflow.com/a/38075782/3090544

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to SQL server database from a Windows 10 UWP app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app)